# Python drop na when I read the excel file

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I load a excel file of 3 million records into pandas, but takes like 45seconds load the file. I just need 3 columns, but I want to know if there is a way without changing the excel file of reduce the times of read the data also if I can load without na values, or anything that reduce the times of loading.

```
import pandas as pd
email_path = r'C:\Users\318459\Desktop\\'
email_path =email_path.replace('\\', '/')
cols = [4, 21, 22]
email=pd.read_excel(f'{email_path}{email_file}', sheet_name="Vigo_Banking_for_Credit",index_col=None, usecols = cols)
```

Regards

Comment: Is your file quite static or often updated? Does the loading time seem long because you often have to modify your code?

Comment: Hi, Often updated

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/60616527/10491422